# How to use external fonts?

Tags: delphi, fonts, resources, delphi-2009

Is it possible to use a font directly from resources in Delphi and how?

I have a problem with the very first steps.Example I cannot include Segoe UI Light font in resources of a project,an exception occurs.And that is only if the file's extension is 'ttf'.

If the written above is not possible then how do I use an external font without deploying the font separately(from executable)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Windows 2000 and later, you can use [AddFontMemResourceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontmemresourceex) to install fonts for your process from memory.

Comment: Just what I was searching for,Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use a font the font must be installed.
But you can fake this, by using `AddFontResource`.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject) ;
begin
  AddFontResource('c:\FONTS\MyFont.TTF') ;
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0) ;
end;

//Before application terminates we must remove our font:
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject) ;
begin
  RemoveFontResource('C:\FONTS\MyFont.TTF') ;
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0) ;
end;
```

As you see the [AddFontResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew) needs a file name. The same stands for [AddFontResourceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourceexw).

So you need a font file. But we can also fake that.

Use [JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/)'s `TjvDataEmbedded` to include your TTF file in your executable. To embed the font file is straightforard. (Right-Click, 'Load from File'...).

At runtime, extract your file in user's temporary directory (see TjvDataEmbedded methods - I don't know now, but it should be something like SaveToFile or similar). Btw you can extract it in any other directory you like. Call `AddFontResource` on it.

Also, according to your requirements, you can extract the file in a memory mapped one and/or in a RAM drive.

HTH

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! Only one thing lasts: How do I assign TForm.Font with the 'installed' font?

Comment: @John: This is good as far as the technical side is concerned - however you **need** to make sure that you have redistribution rights for the font.

Comment: @John: You must know the name of the font. This is easy - install the font, open the WordPad (or similar) and see what the font name appears. Eg. for timesb.ttf the name is 'Times New Roman (Bold)'.

So, in your application you must assign the **font name** (not the file name) to the TForm.Font.

Eg. after installing (by using the above procedure) the mytimes.ttf you will have the line:

    myMainForm.Font.Name:='My Times New Roman';
    myMainForm.Font.Size:=10; //etc.

As an aside, be sure that all the controls of your form have `ParentFont:=True`

Comment: @John: If you are not familiar with changing fonts, perhaps is better to try the above procedure on 'regular' fonts to be sure that you know how it works. (This is just to make your 'debugging life' easier :-) )

Comment: My firemonkey app does not recognized `WM_FONTCHANGE`. How I can use it?