# Embedding a font in delphi

Tags: delphi, fonts, embedded-resource

I'm working on an app that requires a particular barcode true type font that is unlikely to be on the user's PC.

Can I somehow embed the font in the app, or do I need to use the installer to install the font?

Comment: You can do both. I have 1 question, it is your font? or, can you redistribute?

Comment: You can embed it as a resource. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305344/how-to-use-external-fonts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can save it as a resource in the EXE file, and on user's pc, you can extract it as a file using a TResourceStream instance. Then you can call [AddFontResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function. At last, you should send a WM_FONTCHANGE message to all top-level windows in the system (Check Remark section of AddFontResource description in MSDN website).

If you need an example code, let me know.

Comment: Be aware that you might break some copyright laws or license restrictions, if you do not have the redistribution rights for this font.

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion the most easy way is to use [AddFontMemResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in case the font is embedded as a resource into the EXE. It allows loading the font directly from memory, no need to save the font to file.

Code Example:

```
function LoadResourceFont( const ResourceName : string ) : boolean;
var
   ResStream : tResourceStream;
   FontsCount : integer;
   hFont : tHandle;
begin
   ResStream := tResourceStream.Create(hInstance, ResourceName, RT_RCDATA);
   hFont := AddFontMemResourceEx(ResStream.Memory, ResStream.Size, nil, @FontsCount);
   result := (hFont <> 0);
   ResStream.Free();
end;
```

Comment: Nice. For me the code was " ResStream := tResourceStream.Create(hInstance, ResourceName, RT_FONT);" and not RT_RCDATA. I dragged FontAwesome into the "Melander Resource Editor" and it created a FONT typer resource