# Loading font from resource file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am having a Delphi XE Project with the following resource:

[image: Project1]

I have used [**`function LoadResourceFont`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984474/embedding-a-font-in-delphi) and tried the following code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function LoadResourceFontByName( const ResourceName : string; ResType: PChar ) : Boolean;
var
  ResStream  : TResourceStream;
  FontsCount : DWORD;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, ResourceName, ResType);
  try
    Result  := (AddFontMemResourceEx(ResStream.Memory, ResStream.Size, nil, @FontsCount) <> 0);
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;

function LoadResourceFontByID( ResourceID : Integer; ResType: PChar ) : Boolean;
var
  ResStream  : TResourceStream;
  FontsCount : DWORD;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(hInstance, ResourceID, ResType);
  try
    Result  := (AddFontMemResourceEx(ResStream.Memory, ResStream.Size, nil, @FontsCount) <> 0);
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if LoadResourceFontByName('MyFont1', RT_RCDATA) then Label1.Font.Name := 'My Custom Font1';
  if LoadResourceFontByID(2, RT_FONT) then Label2.Font.Name := 'My Custom Font2';   
end.
```

*By the way: I know that I should have redistribution rights for the font if I need to embedded it into my EXE file.*

But the problem is that if the font name ( I have used **My Custom Font1**, **My Custom Font2**) is not the actual name of the font, the font does not load properly and shows an unknown font character.

My question is that whether though I have used **`ResStream.Free`** in the founctions, yet I have to define again **`FormClose`** and **`FormDestroy`** event to protect **Memory Leakage** or not?

Comment: 'Label2.Font[2]' why should it compile? What do you want that statement to mean?

Comment: I need that Label1 Font should be loaded from RCDATA Type Resource and Label2 Font should be loaded from FONT Type Resource.

Comment: How about looking up the definitions of your functions? That will stop you assigning booleans to strings. It will also tell you what to with the return values of your functions.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of type mismatch?

Comment: Anyway. You need to add the font and then check that succeeded. You don't do that. Then you refer to the font by name as with any other font. That's it. It pays to think about what code does rather than blindly copying it. Read it. Understand it. Think about what it does. Read documentation. Don't copy blindly and try stuff at random without any understanding.

Comment: If anybody rectify my blindly copied code and make it compileable, it will be better to me to understand the wrong thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding a font in delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984474/embedding-a-font-in-delphi)

Comment: Just realized that my dupe vote is already linked in the question - sorry

Comment: @HPO - You have what you need in David's comment. You also have it in your code: label1's font assignment works correctly. So why don't you try the same thing with label2?

Comment: Note that the [linked] code leaves the cleanup to the OS, it releases the resource when the application is closed.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: *label1's font assignment works correctly*. No, it doesn't. The code assigns a boolean to `Label1.Font.Name`, which is the first compiler error at line 41. The first line 42 error is the assignment to `Label2.Font[2]`, because TFont does not have a default property.

Comment: @Ken, OK I see, thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 7):

Your code has several errors in it.

1. `LoadResourceFont()` returns a `Boolean`.  You are trying to assign that value to the `TLabel.Font.Name` property, which you cannot do since a `Boolean` is not a `String`.  You are also trying to assign the `Boolean` to a `TLabel.Font[2]` property, which is not even a valid identifier to assign a value to.
2. Your first call to `LoadResourceFont()` is specifying the wrong resource name.
3. The first parameter of `LoadResourceFont()` is a `String`, but your second call to `LoadResourceFont()` is trying to pass the global `Hinstance` variable (an `THandle`) where a `String` is expected.
4. You are trying to load the second font as an RCDATA resource when it is actually a FONT resource instead.

To do what you are attempting, you need to call `LoadResourceFont()` first to load the font(s) into the font table, and then you can set the `TLabel.Font.Name` to the typeface name of the desired font (the name defined inside the TTF file, not the filename or resource name), eg:

```
function LoadResourceFontByName( const ResourceName : string; ResType: PChar ) : Boolean;
var
  ResStream : TResourceStream;
  FontsCount : DWORD;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, ResourceName, ResType);
  try
    Result := (AddFontMemResourceEx(ResStream.Memory, ResStream.Size, nil, @FontsCount) <> 0);
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;

function LoadResourceFontByID( ResourceID : Integer; ResType: PChar ) : Boolean;
var
  ResStream : TResourceStream;
  FontsCount : DWORD;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(hInstance, ResourceID, ResType);
  try
    Result := (AddFontMemResourceEx(ResStream.Memory, ResStream.Size, nil, @FontsCount) <> 0);
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if LoadResourceFontByName('MyFont1', RT_RCDATA) then
    Label1.Font.Name := 'My Font Name 1';

  if LoadResourceFontByID(2, RT_FONT) then
    Label2.Font.Name := 'My Font Name 2';
end;
```

Comment: I suspect this won't work as AddFontMemResourceEx looks like it is retrieving a pseudo handle. Think about when font count is greater than 1, which font's handle will be returned. Also RemoveFontMemResourceEx calls the handle " a handle to a font-resource", which is more accurate I believe.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: You are absolutely right. First chance exception at $75965B68. Exception class EResNotFound with message 'Resource 2 not found'. Process Project1.exe (19900) and the Label2 Font is also not loaded.

Comment: @HPOwner That would make sense if your second resource is getting compiled into the executable using a string name of `'2'` instead of a numeric ID of `2`. Check your executable with a resource viewer. Try `LoadResourceFontByName('2')`

Comment: @HPO - That's a different error in which you are either not compiling the font resource into the executable, or not identifying it correctly. According to the picture in your question, you may have to change RT_RCDATA to RT_FONT in Remy's code. Also check the executable with an external resource editor to verify the font resource's existence and its identifier.

Comment: ... you have to begin trying to understand the code you use.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz good point about `RT_FONT`, I missed that in the screenshot. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Code is compiling, exe is running without any error, but UNKNOWN FONT is loaded not from RESOURCE. I have banned for questioning, so I am unable to ask this error again. Kindly unbar me.

Comment: @HPOwner: you are not banned, you can still [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36224624/edit) to make it better, then it may be reopened for answering.

Comment: @RemyLebeau We'd need a similar `UnloadResourceFontByID` which calls `RemoveFontMemResourceEx` on `Form.Destroy`, is that right?

Comment: @geneb. `RemoveFontMemResourceEx()` needs to be passed the handle that `AddFontMemResourceEx()` returns. So there is no need for a `UnloadResourceFontByID()`, unless the `ID` in question is cached along with its handle somewhere, such as in a `TDictionary`.  A `TList` (or `TList<THandle>`) would make more sense, where `LoadResourceFontBy...()` adds the returned handle to a list, and then you can iterate the list later to remove the mem resource of each handle in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`Label.Font` doesn't have subscripts, so `Label2.Font[2]` is invalid.

Also, assigning the boolean result of your `LoadFontResource` function to a `Label.Font` of any kind will clearly not work, as that boolean result will never be a **font**.

I'd suggest you learn the basics of programming using Delphi and also study the VCL/FMX documentation for TFont before worrying about loading custom fonts from memory.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question.

Comment: Really this is not solved my problem. I need to compile and work correctly my code.

Comment: @Rob: The question says *I'm not able to compile*. I explained why it won't compile - it's invalid code for the reasons I described. There is no other question asked or problem described (the title does neither).