# Firemonkey cannot see dynamic loaded font in Windows

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

When I have loaded a dynamic font in Windows with

```
AddFontResource("myfontpath.ttf");
```

I need to choose it on the canvas and draw text with it:

```
Canvas.Font.Family := "myfontname"
```

On OS X and iOS it works fine! - because loading of the custom font is done through the .plist outside of the application. However, on Windows it does not recognize the font and falls back to a standard font.

I found these topics indicating that it is a general problem with FMX. 
[Firemonkey: Adding a font from resource to memory and using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433459/firemonkey-adding-a-font-from-resource-to-memory-and-using-it) and [Install font in firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985465/install-font-in-firemonkey?lq=1)

These questions do NOT end up with a solution, though one of them suggest working with styles, but in my situation I am using the font on a custom non-styled component (inherited from TControl and not from TStyledControl)

**Did anyone find a solution or a workaround?**

PS. Installing the font by the installer in Windows is not an option because the font should be hidden for other applications. It is not a text font!
I use AddFontResourceEx( ... ,FR_PRIVATE, ... ) to achieve this, but the FMX problem I describe is the same with AddFontResource.

Comment: There is no answer to this question in the other topics.

Comment: Duplicate indicates that the questions are the same. The fact that none of the other answers solve your problem doesn't matter. Sorry.

Comment: So how can I ask if anyone have found an answer? - because I have not enough points to comment on other questions.

Comment: I've given you sufficient rep to be able to comment